# RockBox not boots

Tags: mp3-player, rockbox, sansa

I have Sanasa 16gb Clip Sport+ mp3 player. I flashed Rockbox firmware to it:

[image]

But Sansa original software is still running on it even I turn off/on device.

How to run RockBox on my Sansa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SanDisk Clip Sport is not supported by Rockbox.  It cannot be supported due to hardware limitations.

http://forums.rockbox.org/index.php?topic=51782.0

Comment: Does it means Clip is supported while Clip Sport is not supported?